# Inserting PDF Page on Existing PDF

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to insert two pdfs, the first pdf is the main pdf and the second is the one I'd like to take and append to the first pdf, under the same name. The goal is to open the pdf and append and that's it.

```
import fitz
doc1 = fitz.open("test1.pdf")
doc2 = fitz.open("test2.pdf")
doc1.insertPDF(doc2)
doc2.save("test2.pdf")
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\fitz\fitz.py", line 3537, in save
    raise ValueError("save to original must be incremental")
ValueError: save to original must be incremental
```

If there's any other way to do this please let me know, through Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to append your modifications to the existing pdf file *(incremental save)* you can use `saveIncr()` method which internally calls the  `save` method with the correct arguments.

`saveIncr()` saves the document incrementally by calling

```
doc.save(doc.name, incremental=True, encryption=PDF_ENCRYPT_KEEP)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you very much Vishal.
Just so people know, PDF_ENCRYPT_KEEP is under the fitz library, so you would need to reference fitz (fitz.PDF_ENCRYPT_KEEP)

Comment: Thank you for your supplementary notes.@Anfaaa